# Java/Android - Start New Activity Flag Error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am receiving the following error while testing my app in the emulator:

```
05-20 09:33:20.755 16679-16679/midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp, PID: 16679
                                                                         android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
                                                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
                                                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
                                                                             at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
                                                                             at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
                                                                             at midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.appUpdater.onPostExecute(appUpdater.java:52)
                                                                             at midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.appUpdater.onPostExecute(appUpdater.java:18)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But I do not understand, I have added the flag to the intent. I have even tried alternating between setFlags and addFlags with no success. What might I be missing?

```
public class appUpdater extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {
   private Context c;
public  appUpdater(Context context) {
    this.c = context;
}

    protected String doInBackground(URL... appUrl) {

        // download app file, provided a URL

        String location = c.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/app.apk";
        try {
            URL url = appUrl[0];
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(location);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;

            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        output.close();
        input.close();


        } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        return location;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String saveLocation) {

        // install app file

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Log.i("Location of app is: ", " " + saveLocation);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(saveLocation)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        c.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine (I'd use `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` myself) so my I am guessing that you either edit wrong file or your app is not being rebuilt correctly (or at all) so your changes are not applied or for some reasons new build is not installed on the device/emulator. I'd clean the project and rebuild and then step with debugger (and also inspect if intent really holds the flag).

Answer (score -1):

you context is not activity `context`, you should use activity `context` or add flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `intent`